# Power BI Matrix with Data from Unrelated Columns in Related tables

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables that, by themselves, are unrelated. A special table has been built to make a connection between them. However, even though parts can be connected, others cannot, because no relationship actually exists. I've been asked to create a list of some kind that shows situations where X exists, **or** where Y exists, **or** where X and Y both exist.

Here's a sample of made-up data that has a similar structure.

Table X

| State | X Event |
| --- | --- |
| AZ | 10/4/2021 |
| AZ | 12/15/2021 |
| CA | 8/24/2022 |
| ID | 11/14/2022 |
| ID | 12/2/2022 |
| ID | 12/25/2022 |
| UT | 11/4/2021 |
| UT | 1/27/2022 |
| UT | 6/18/2021 |
| OR | 5/12/2021 |
| OR | 7/27/2021 |
| WA | 5/25/2022 |
| WA | 11/2/2022 |
| WA | 11/8/2022 |

Table Y

| City | X Event |
| --- | --- |
| Bakersfield | 4/16/2021 |
| Boise | 11/21/2022 |
| Denver | 2/16/2021 |
| Eugene | 1/20/2022 |
| Fresno | 8/14/2021 |
| Las Vegas | 2/10/2021 |
| Medford | 7/21/2022 |
| Pocatello | 7/16/2022 |
| Portland | 11/3/2021 |
| Reno | 2/19/2022 |
| Sacramento | 10/18/2021 |
| Seattle | 7/16/2021 |

The special table adds a State value to Table Y so it can be joined to Table X. Each State has an ID, each City has an ID, and each Event has an ID, but the X Events and the Y Events have different IDs because they are not related.

My output needs to resemble this:
[Sample Output Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2LcJ.png)

But Power BI won't allow it. For example, there is one X Event date in CA and three Y Event dates in cities in CA. But because the X Event dates have nothing to do with the Y Event dates, they won't line up.

**Is there a way to tell Power BI that the X Event column and the Y Event column are unrelated to each other but should appear side-by-side anyway because they are related to the State column?**

(Sorry, I don't know why my tables in this post are not formatting correctly. They look fine in the preview but not when published.)

Comment: Please, add a "special table" that "adds "a State value to Table Y".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved in Power Query Using Merge Queries.
First populate State column in Table Y. Then merge two tables.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This looks very promising. I have too much data, and it stalled on my first attempt, but I have some more options to explore. Thank you!